# CMake + MSVC build tools 2015 - what to do after invoking cmake?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build, cmake

<sub>I've never used CMake on Windows, or with MSVC, before; so this is a newbie question.</sub>

I've installed CMake and some minimal freely-downloadable "Microsoft Visual C++ build tools 2015" (from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)) on a Windows 10 machine. I have my CMake-based project (which builds fine on Linux) checked out, and I'm ready to go.

So, in a shell window, I do:

```
PS C:\Users\joeuser\the_project> mkdir build
... etc. etc. ...
PS C:\Users\joeuser\the_project> cd build
PS C:\Users\joeuser\the_project\build> cmake ../
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Selecting Windows SDK version  to target Windows 10.0.15063.
-- lots of checks here
-- etc. etc.
```

and that's done. So far so good. But - what now? On a Unix'ish system, I would execute `make`, and perhaps `make install`; and maybe `make clean` later on. My questions are:

- Do the MSVC tools I'm using have an equivalent of `make`? I've head about nmake and msys but I'm not sure those are relevant here.
- What do I do now in order to build, install or clean the build directory?
- Is it better/easier/more common practice to use a different CMake generator in my scenario?

Comment: @vre: 1. Why the extra switches? 2. And how do I do cleaning or installation?

Comment: Because CMake directs those arguments to the underlying build tool (make, MSBuild, ...). To install you would choose `--target INSTALL`, for running tests `--target RUN_TESTS`, and for cleaning you have to use `--target ALL_BUILD --config Debug -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal /t:Clean` because Visual Studio solution does not contain a clean target but MSBuild has one.

Comment: @vre: Can you make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making my previous comments an answer:

You would then call the underlying build tool directly via CMake:

```
cmake --build . --target ALL_BUILD --config Debug -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal
```

This gives you an almost quiet build process as you are used to from `make`.

> Why the hell do I have to provide so much arguments to CMake?

Because CMake is a build system generator and directs those arguments to the underlying build tool (`make`, `MSBuild`, `nmake`, ...). The underlying build tool may have different naming conventions for targets etc., e.g. make users provide almost always the targets `all`, `clean`, and `install`. But the Visual Studio solution generated by CMake uses by default `ALL_BUILD`, `INSTALL`, `RUN_TESTS`. There is no `CLEAN` target. Using MSBuild,

- To **install** your solution you would select `--target INSTALL`.
- For **running tests**, you would select `--target RUN_TESTS`.
- For **cleaning** you have to use `--target ALL_BUILD --config Debug -- /nologo /verbosity:minimal /t:Clean` because the Visual Studio solution does not contain a clean target but MSBuild provides one.

Further important arguments of MSBuild are:

- `/maxcpucount:<numberOfCpus>` (to limit the number of CPUs the build process is using) and
- `"/l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=<YOUR_LOGFILE_NAME>"` to save MSBuild output to file.